# PHP while loop paging

Tags: php, while-loop

I have the following PHP loop:

```
if( have_rows('home_projecten') ) {
    $i = 0;
    while( have_rows('home_projecten') ) {
        $i++;
        the_row();
        if($i == 1) { 
            echo '<div class="slide">'; 
        }
        echo '<div class="project"></div>';
        if($i == 3) { 
            $i = 0;
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to split my 'project items' in slides, with 3 items per slide. Currently, this is working fine for every 'full' slide, meaning a slide with 3 projects. When `$i` becomes larger than 3, a new slide is added.

However, when I have for example 4 projects, the second slide div is not closed anymore, as I never reach `$i == 3` again.. I know I could fix this with counting the array and doing something with that, but I have no idea how..

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Close the div after the end of the loop, if it needs to be closed? You could set a flag when you've closed the div, if it's not set when you exit the loop, then close it.

Comment: This becomes way easier, if you output the first `<div class="slide">` before the loop, and the last closing `</div>` after. Then all you have to do inside the loop, is output `</div> <div class="slide">` when you cross your elements-per-div threshold.

Comment: @CBroe this worked perfectly, thank you so much! Had been breaking my head around this, while the fix was so easy. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @droopsnoot I went with the solution CBroe provided, but thanks anyway for another good solution!

Comment: Yes, that's a much neater way of doing it.